# What can I do to stop a running toilet with this type of flush system?

Tags: toilet

Do I need to replace the “grey part” water keeps coming in and won’t stop even with the sensor bar all the way up. I did fix my other toilet that had a running water problem but I have never seen this setup before.
Is there anything specific I need to buy to help this?

[image]

Comment: Probably looking at a replacement of fill valve than a repair.  They are usually inexpensive and usually hard to repair.  Take picture and/or fill valve to plumbing/hardware store for matching.

Comment: @crip659 meant "_not_ hard to repair".  Be not afraid.  You can do it!

Comment: I'm seeing some mold or water damage on the wall there.  Might be better off getting a whole new toilet that fits better and doesn't touch that spot.

Comment: FWIW: This seems to be the fill valve (https://www.amazon.com/Fluidmaster-703AP4-Specialty-Conservation-Flapperless/dp/B004TPTFEE) for $12 it just needs replaced.

Comment: @Willk  I did mean trying to take apart a fill valve to replace/repair pieces can be difficult, replacing the whole fill valve is easy.

Comment: @Willk  I think crip659 meant that it's harder to repair than replace. I agree with him/her. Adding up the repair kits are probably more expensive the a new valve.

Comment: Wall looks like perfectly normal "not properly painted before toilet placed, lid left in place while painting, looks bad/dirty with the lid off."

Comment: Thank you. I  called around and found the the fill valve at ACE. replaced and everything is back to normal. Found out that I have a leak when I turned off the water from the knob. So another project! Thank you all for this.

Answer (score 2):

Replacement fill valve is likely your option